# Typescript: global.d.ts not found

Tags: typescript

`/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/global.d.ts"]
}
```

`src/global.d.ts`

```
type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
interface JsonMap extends Record<string, JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
type Json = JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray

declare module '*.json' {
  const value: Json
  export default value
}
```

`Cannot find name JsonPrimitive`

Why can't TS find the global types??

P.S. I know `global.d.ts` is NOT the preferred way to get types, but Typescript DOES support that features..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you get the error, I tried this with Typescript v4.0.3 and the `d.ts` files are getting picked up just fine.

Perhaps you should add `declare` before each `type` or `interface` definition, but I don't think that's the problem.

If you are compiling specific `.ts` file via command line, don't forget to include the `.d.ts` file as well:

```sh
tsc src/sample.ts src/global.d.ts
```

or compile with specified project:

(in project root)

```
tsc -p .
```